# Adding Data To PHP Array Values

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if the following was possible since a Google search came up with zero answers.

Let's say I have the following array:

```
$data[] = array();
$data[] = "value 1";
$data[] = "value 2";
```

And at the beginning of each value I need to add `this is` which would be consistent in each value.

How could I accomplish this?

I tried:

```
$addData = "this is ";
$data[] = array();
$data[] = $addData . "value 1";
$data[] = $addData . "value 2";
```

The reason I was hoping for a solution like this is because the value of `$addData` may change, but the actual values will remain the same.

For example I have the following code:

```
 $directory = "admin/";
 $redirect[] = array();
 $redirect[] = "page1.php";
 $redirect[] = "page2.php";
 $redirect[] = "index.php";
 if(in_array($directory . basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]), $redirect)) {
  header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
}
```

And I need to add `admin` to each value, but dynamically that way if my array list grows then I do not have to edit 10+ array values.

Ultimately I'd like to change the `$directory` value just once if I needed to.

EDIT:

Ok, so I've tried this:

```
 $directory = "admin/";
 $current = $directory . basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
 $redirect[] = "page1.php";
 $redirect[] = "page2.php";
 $redirect[] = "admin/index.php";
 if(in_array($current, $redirect)) {
  header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
}
```

I added the directory manually to the last `redirect[]` value.

Then I added a `$current` variable which outputs the current script name with `admin/` before it such as `admin/index.php'.

My assumption is that it would redirect a page at `http://example.com/admin/index.php` but it's also redirecting `http://example.com/index.php`.

i want to redirect any files in the directory `admin` but the files must be in the array that way certain files in the `admin` directory do not get redirected. This snippet is in my config file and included on every page.

`http://example.com/admin/index.php` should redirect but `http://example.com/index.php` should not.

Comment: Can't you just use `basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])` as needle without the `$directory`?! (Also: `$redirect[] = array();` is adding an empty array as first element into your `$redirect`; What you probably want is: `$redirect = array();`)

Comment: I'm only looking to redirect files within a directory of `admin`. The reason I want to include it is just in case I have two `index.php` files or two of any files at all that only the one in that specific directory get's redirected.

Comment: But if you add the directory to all values, all values will have that directory... so it wouldn't matter if you add them or not.

Comment: That's what I need. In this line `if(in_array($directory . basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]), $redirect)) {` this has the directory in it `$directory . basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])` so if the values have it then it will be checking the directory of the current page and the array values.

Comment: I don't get it. When you don't use `$directory` in `in_array()` and don't add it to any values, you don't have to do anything with `$directory`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to work `$directory` into `in_array()`. I think I'm complicating things lol

Comment: Simple: Just don't use `$directory` here: `if(in_array($directory . basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]), $redirect)) {` and don't add it to any array values.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want that `http://example.com/admin/index.php` gets redirected, but it doesn't? Or does it redirect to `http://example.com/index.php`? No idea what you want to do here.

Comment: i want to redirect any files in the directory `admin` but the files must be in the array that way certain files in the `admin` directory do not get redirected. This snippet is in my config file and included on every page.

`http://example.com/admin/index.php` should redirect but `http://example.com/index.php` should not.

Comment: Then just do something like this: `if(in_array(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]),$redirect) && basename(dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])) == "admin")`

Comment: That solves my issue. Post it as an answer so I may accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to redirect if the current file is in the admin directory and the file is also in the `$redirect` array, then you can also do this with two parts:

```
if(in_array(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]),$redirect) &&  //File is in $redirect 
   basename(dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])) == "admin")    //File is in admin dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your current script you can either add $directory to each value like so:

```
 $directory = "admin/";
 $redirect[] = array();
 $redirect[] = $directory . "page1.php";
 $redirect[] = $directory . "page2.php";
 $redirect[] = $directory . "index.php";
 if(in_array($directory . basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]), $redirect)) {
  header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
}
```

and then later on in the script when you want to add another (dynamic) array item:

```
$redirect[] = $directory . $varStoringAnotherFilename;
```

or you can create a helper function and modify all existing values in one go using array_map:

```
function setDirectory($file) {
  return "admin/" . $file;
}

 $redirect[] = array();
 $redirect[] = "page1.php";
 $redirect[] = "page2.php";
 $redirect[] = "index.php";
 if(in_array($directory . basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]), array_map('setDirectory', $redirect))) {
  header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
}
```

but it would be easier to just skip $directory in your condition:

```
 $redirect[] = array();
 $redirect[] = "page1.php";
 $redirect[] = "page2.php";
 $redirect[] = "index.php";
 if(in_array(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]), $redirect)) {
  header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
}
```

Comment: I tried the first one and my main `index.php` is stuck in an infinite loop of redirects even though I've included the directory.

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve you should just skip $directory in your condition (last snippet) or use array_map (second snippet) which will produce an array where each value was processed using a function. You can find out more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php